# Enumerating figures in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, floats, enumerate, labels, presentations

i am trying to do a presentation with beamer and i can't find a way to enumerate figures,(give figures corresponding numbers).
i have tried label command, but it didn't work.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Caract\'{e}ristiqus de la commande adaptative}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=11cm,height=6cm]{t3l.eps}  
\caption{Caract\'{e}ristiques de la commande MRAS par la m\'{e}thode de Lyapunov}
\label{fig15}  
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: By default they aren't labelled, because presentations would be weird if they referred to Figure X from slide Y - the audience won't remember the numbered figures. Instead, repeating a figure is often the suggested use-case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

`\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]`

in the preamble. Your code will become:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Caract\'{e}ristiqus de la commande adaptative}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=11cm,height=6cm]{t3l.eps}  
\caption{Caract\'{e}ristiques de la commande MRAS par la m\'{e}thode de Lyapunov}
\label{fig15}  
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much , it worked !